# What is an efficient way to place random numbers in a buffer for writing to files?

Tags: c++, linux

I am trying to mess with using basic Linux system calls and writing good code by writing a program that will write random bytes to a file. I've envisioned a couple different ways of doing this, but I'm curious of what methods are more efficient. Please feel free to give me improvements on my code or suggest completely different methods; I'm just trying to improve.

Currently, I'm generating random `uint32_t`'s using `mt19937` from C++11's random and placing them in a buffer using memcpy before writing to the file. Is this a very efficient way to do this?

Would I be better off initializing the buffer to 0 with a memset and using or'ing/bit-shifting? With that, I am forgetting how to/if there is a way to do something like `*(buffer + offset) |= (random32 << BUF_SIZE - sizeof(random32) * currIndex)` and get C++ to place all 32 bits rather than a single char.

```
//Here's the actual buffer manipulation/write code I currently have
std::mt19937 rand(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());

    for(ssize_t i = 0; i < size; i += BUF_SIZE)
    {
        //Fill the buffer with random uint32_t's (the buffer is a multiple of 32 right now)
        char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
        for(int j = 0; j < BUF_SIZE; j += sizeof(uint32_t))
        {
            uint32_t num = rand();
            std::fprintf(stderr, "DEBUG: generated random number %x\n", num);
            std::memcpy(buffer + j, &num, sizeof(num));
        }

        // Write buffer to file
        ssize_t bytes_left = size - i;
        ssize_t bytes_to_write = BUF_SIZE > bytes_left ? bytes_left : BUF_SIZE;
        std::fprintf(stderr, "DEBUG: writing %zu bytes to buffer\n", bytes_to_write);
        if(write(fd, buffer, bytes_to_write) != bytes_to_write)
        {
            std::fprintf(stderr, "Failed to write at %zu", i);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Avoid using `memset` and `memcpy` in C++ programs. Generally `::std::fill` and `::std::copy` are better choices.

Comment: If you want to write a large amount of arbitrary binary data to a file you should consider memory mapping the file. C++ doesn't have a portable interface for it, but POSIX systems support it. You basically presize the file, map the file to your address space and handle it essentially like a C array.

Comment: Why a C-style array and not `std::array`?

Comment: There's no answer to `what's the most efficient way' questions. You have to try different approaches, time them and pick the best. What works well in one situation will not work well in another.

Comment: `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/tmp/my_random_file count=some_size`

Comment: @Omnifarious Thanks. Just curious, is there substantial reason to do this other than bad practice of mixing C and C++?

Comment: @john I wasn't looking for the magical all-encompassing perfect way to do it. I'm just curious what ideas would be thrown around, and I specifically compared two different ways.

Comment: @JesperJuhl C-style arrays are just what my university uses. I also might eventually switch back down to C, so I might as well get used to some of the oddities associated with them. I'm not writing this program for functionality really (I know dd exists). I just want to experiment.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks! I'll have to think about that if I ever want to make more software like this.

Comment: @mcox59 Unfortunately, Stack Overflow is for asking specific questions to which there are specific answers. This question is rather open ended, essentially prompting a brain-storm (*"I'm just curious what ideas would be thrown around"*) and will likely be closed for being off topic. Edit : If you want feedback on working code, you should visit https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead. But be sure to read their help pages as I'm unfamiliar with there guidelines and I'm not sure if this question would be a good fit as-if.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I guess I kind of knew that stack exchange was more specific than this. Thanks, I’ll take a look at that.

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
::std::array<char, BUF_SIZE> buffer;
::std::generate(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), rand);
```

instead of the loop you're currently using to fill up the buffer. Then adjust the rest of the program to use a `buffer` that's an array that has it's own `size` method and the like rather than a bare `char` array like you have now.

That's more the C++ way than what you're doing. Minimize the use of bare pointers and arrays. Use the standard algorithms where possible. If you find yourself writing a `for` loop, look to see if the algorithms library has already written the loop for you.

And that goes for code that *isn't* already in the standard library as well. If you find yourself writing a for loop, stop. Instead, figure out how to abstract what that for loop is doing into a reusable function so that you can write the for loop once and use it in a lot of situations.

And if you want to understand how the standard library works, then take it upon yourself to write those functions.

Don't Repeat Yourself is one of the absolutely most important programming principles. Larry Wall famously recast it as 'laziness'. Learn how to never repeat yourself. If the standard library makes you uncomfortable because you don't know what it's doing, try using compiler explorer to see the assembly language. And try writing the standard library functions yourself. Knowing your tools up, down, and sideways is also really important. So this work is worth doing.

But, that's what you should be doing, not repeating yourself and training yourself to do it over and over again. Train yourself to do it the right way. And if you're uncomfortable with not knowing the details, write the details instead of writing it the wrong way so you can see the details.

Comment: I'd consider using `std::vector` instead if that `buffer` has to move around at all. `buffer` is likely going to be big and moving an `std::array` can be slow where as moving an `std::vector` is a constant time operation. In addition, you may not have sufficient stack space and the buffer size cannot be a runtime value with `std::array`. Edit : But this answer is true to the original code.

Comment: I’m sure this is more efficient and more C++ style, but I’d kind of prefer something slightly more lower level, closer to the implementation of std::generate than just letting C++ handle everything for me.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I’m going to have to write it to a file either way. I’m not sure, but I doubt a vector is really more efficient than an array just writing to a file. I feel like generating all of the extra template/generic functionality for a vector just to use a system call that is implemented in C code wont be all that helpful?

Comment: @mcox59 There's practically no overhead beyond that of `new`ing an array and a couple of integers. I feel you may not fully appreciate the work optimizers do to remove overhead from abstraction (of which there is very little here). Templates also have no impact on runtime *at all* and are only used during compilation. After that, they are exactly the same as if you had written the class without templates. Edit : The `std::vector` isn't about being more efficient at writing to a file. It's about not breaking the stack and avoiding copies if your code ever gets more complicated.

Comment: @mcox59 - If you want to learn how `::std::generate` works, that's one thing. But writing code that basically duplicates it in a situation in which you could use it instead is unwise for a number of reasons. Partly, what you do is likely going to be less efficient. Partly, you're more likely to make a mistake, and errors in C++ programs involving arrays almost always have security implications. And partly, once someone knows about `::std::generate`, your code is harder to understand.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I do know that templates don’t effect runtime and that C++ and the standard library are very well optimized, but, in the long run, I’d rather be the person optimizing code than using optimized code (or at least somewhat capable of it). I think experimenting with this slightly lower level stuff now will be more helpful for what I want to do than always relying on the standard library and other libraries. But then again I’m a little weird and not adhering to great new age practices I guess.

Comment: @mcox59 Yes, that is not the usual modern C++ philosophy. You may do as you please, but it's important to realize that the mentality of trusting the compiler is wide-spread because it's useful. The code you write only describes a behavior and is won't necessarily do exactly what you expected "underneath". Compilers can transform your code extensively according to the [as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if). Optimizers have become *smart* and they can take advantage of platform specific quirks (which you can't easily do, specially if you're portable).

Comment: @mcox59 I guess a more important philosophy to keep in mind at this point is that it's better to write clear code than optimized code. The reasoning is that clearer code is always more useful, but optimized code isn't more useful unless it's actually reducing a bottleneck. Unless a problem is *measured*, premature optimization will likely just complicate your code for no gain. In this example, the bottleneck is likely to be the file I/O. Speeding up anything else will probably just lead to spending more time waiting for your hard drive anyway. But again, that would need to be measured.

Comment: @mcox59 As a final note, it's not clear to me that you are aware of the distinction between optimized code and optimizing compilers. Optimized code means code that is written to be as fast or small as possible. Optimizing compilers (every good compiler) will take code and will optimize it internally (to the extent that it is able to). The standard library isn't just fast because it's written in an optimal way. Compilers are designed to be good at simply removing the layers of abstraction, producing a result that is usually equivalent or very close to manually optimized low level code.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux and Omnifarious Thanks again, I really appreciate the feedback. I understand that the ideal with modern C++ and most modern languages is to use more understandable, concise code, but I have an attraction to trying to implement/reimplement things in my own way and learning more about it as I go. I should get better/more comfortable with using interfaces/libraries, but I really want to understand the underlying details so I can know better how to use it and why it is how it is. Especially when a lot of times documentation for different libraries doesn’t elaborate on them.

Comment: @mcox59 Then you may be more comfortable learning C instead. It's community is generally more low-level and hardware oriented and more in line with your vision. The features and documentation also seems to be adapted accordingly.

Comment: @mcox59 - I wouldn't go so far as to say you should be learning C instead. I think, maybe, what you should do is set about figuring out how to write all the C++ standard library things for yourself. I also have a strong impulse to know how the things I'm using work. But the way to do that isn't choosing poor practices. The way to do that is to dig into the good practices and figure out what's underneath them. I highly recommend tools like compiler explorer and the like, and writing your own copies of stuff like `::std::generate` to understand them.